# Why is Javascript not revalidating the MongoDB data on the page when I insert new documents?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I use *Next.js 13 Server Components* to query MongoDB in the component

The data is rendered to the page.
If something changes in the database and I refresh the page, the changes should also be reflected in the page.

This also works, but only in development mode (npm run dev).

But when I start the server with *npm run start*, the *new* database data is not reflected on the page. It's gets it just one time.

With *npm run build* the route is marked as Static. Is this correct?

/lib/mongodb.js

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Invalid/Missing environment variable: "MONGODB_URI"')
}

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI
const options = {}

let client
let clientPromise

  console.log("DEVELOPMENT MODE MONGODB")
  // In development mode, use a global variable so that the value
  // is preserved across module reloads caused by HMR (Hot Module Replacement).
  if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options)
    global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect()
  }
  clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise


// Export a module-scoped MongoClient promise. By doing this in a
// separate module, the client can be shared across functions.
export default clientPromise
```

tickets.js
This component runs on the server

```
import clientPromise from "../../../lib/mongodb";

export default async function Tickets() {
    const client = await clientPromise;

    const db = client.db('sample_mflix');
    const collection = db.collection('contact');
    const result = await collection.find().toArray()
    console.log("Database fetched")

    return(
    <>
    {result.map(el => {
        return (
            <div key={el._id}>
                {el.name}
                {el.email}
                {el.message}
            </div>
        )
    })}
    </>
    )
}
```

Comment: But when I refresh the site it should fetch again from database or am I wrong? And also this is a server component.

Comment: Completely misread--my bad.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to caching feature of next js server components. Read more about it [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components)

> Caching: By rendering on the server, the result can be cached and reused on subsequent requests and across users. This can improve performance and reduce cost by reducing the amount of rendering and data fetching done on each request.

The solution that maybe work for you is [dynamic rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#dynamic-rendering)

> With Dynamic Rendering, routes are rendered for each user at request time.
>
> Dynamic rendering is useful when a route has data that is personalized to the user or has information that can only be known at request time, such as cookies or the URL's search params.